# How to remove a element of specific class created using Javascript when clicked outside the box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to remove an element created using the JavaScript of specific class when clicked outside the box .
I have used created a color-picker using `.createElement` . Add a class to it .
Now I wanted to remove that picker when outside of its parent element is clicked as sometimes users don't pick the color and on every click a color-picker is created .

**How my function works :**

- Click on circle option will open up to change : `borderColor` or `backgroundColor`
- When one option is chosen the color of that property is changed

```js
var restyleBG = document.getElementsByClassName("restyleBackground");
restyleBG[0].addEventListener('click', changeBGcolor);

function changeBGcolor() {
  let optionChooseBackground = document.getElementById("optionToChooseBackground");
  optionChooseBackground.style.display = "block";
  let optionChooseTag = optionChooseBackground.getElementsByTagName("p")

  for (let j = 0; j < optionChooseTag.length; j++) {
    optionChooseTag[j].onclick = function() {
      var varWantToChange = optionChooseTag[j].innerHTML;

      let optionToChoosePicker = document.getElementById("optionToChoose");
      let colourPicker = document.createElement("input");
      colourPicker.type = "color";
      colourPicker.className = "colour-picker";
      optionToChoosePicker.appendChild(colourPicker);
      colourPicker.click();
      colourPicker.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var colorPickerVal = colourPicker.value;
        if (varWantToChange == "borderColor") {
          restyleBG[0].style.borderColor = colorPickerVal;
        } else if (varWantToChange == "backgroundColor") {
          restyleBG[0].style.backgroundColor = colorPickerVal;
        }
      })

    }
  }
}
```

```css
#optionToChoose {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
}

#optionToChooseBackground {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba(165, 42, 42, 0.205);
  display: none;
}

#clockOuterCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 42vw;
  height: 42vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255, 62, 62);
  background-color: rgb(253, 133, 133);
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="optionToChooseBackground">
  <div id="optionToChoose">
    <h3>Choose a style want to change :</h3>
    <h4>Border</h4>
    <p>borderColor</p>
    <p>backgroundColor</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="clockOuterCircle" class="restyleBackground"></div>
```

Upto now works as needed but creating pickers on each click whether choosing a color or not (*not used a on-change event on color picker which executes when color value is changed and remove the picker but this don't come in handy when user just click the property and don't change the color*).

The method I tried is in below snippet that when outside of color-picker parent element is clicked  it removes the created element but this is throwing error when clicked .

```js
var restyleBG = document.getElementsByClassName("restyleBackground");
restyleBG[0].addEventListener('click', changeBGcolor);

function changeBGcolor() {
  let optionChooseBackground = document.getElementById("optionToChooseBackground");
  optionChooseBackground.style.display = "block";
  let optionChooseTag = optionChooseBackground.getElementsByTagName("p")

  for (let j = 0; j < optionChooseTag.length; j++) {
    optionChooseTag[j].onclick = function() {
      var varWantToChange = optionChooseTag[j].innerHTML;

      let optionToChoosePicker = document.getElementById("optionToChoose");
      let colourPicker = document.createElement("input");
      colourPicker.type = "color";
      colourPicker.className = "colour-picker";
      optionToChoosePicker.appendChild(colourPicker);
      colourPicker.click();
      colourPicker.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var colorPickerVal = colourPicker.value;
        if (varWantToChange == "borderColor") {
          restyleBG[0].style.borderColor = colorPickerVal;
        } else if (varWantToChange == "backgroundColor") {
          restyleBG[0].style.backgroundColor = colorPickerVal;
        }
      })

      optionChooseBackground.addEventListener('click', optionChooseBackgroundClose)

      function optionChooseBackgroundClose() {
        if (event.target == optionChooseBackground) {
          let optionToChoosePicker = document.getElementById("optionToChoose");
          optionToChoosePicker.removeChild(colourPicker);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#optionToChoose {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
}

#optionToChooseBackground {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba(165, 42, 42, 0.205);
  display: none;
}

#clockOuterCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 42vw;
  height: 42vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255, 62, 62);
  background-color: rgb(253, 133, 133);
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="optionToChooseBackground">
  <div id="optionToChoose">
    <h3>Choose a style want to change :</h3>
    <h4>Border</h4>
    <p>borderColor</p>
    <p>backgroundColor</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="clockOuterCircle" class="restyleBackground"></div>
```

Thank you very much in advance

Any better method to remove picker than above mentioned is most welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Edit: I removed new ids. HTML remains as yours.

```js
var restyleBG = document.getElementsByClassName("restyleBackground");

restyleBG[0].addEventListener('click', changeBGcolor);

function changeBGcolor() {
  let optionChooseBackground = document.getElementById("optionToChooseBackground");
  optionChooseBackground.style.display = "block";

  
  let optionToChoosePicker = document.getElementById("optionToChoose");
  let colourPicker = document.createElement("input");
  colourPicker.type = "color";
  colourPicker.className = "colour-picker";
  optionToChoosePicker.appendChild(colourPicker);
  

 let optionChooseTag = optionChooseBackground.getElementsByTagName("p")

var varWantToChange = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < optionChooseTag.length; j++) {
    optionChooseTag[j].addEventListener("click", () => {
    varWantToChange = optionChooseTag[j].innerHTML;
    });

}
  
      
     
      colourPicker.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var colorPickerVal = colourPicker.value;
        if (varWantToChange === "borderColor") {
          restyleBG[0].style.borderColor = colorPickerVal;
        } else if (varWantToChange === "backgroundColor") {
          restyleBG[0].style.backgroundColor = colorPickerVal;
        }
      })
}
```

```css
#optionToChoose {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
}

#optionToChooseBackground {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba(165, 42, 42, 0.205);
  display: none;
}

#clockOuterCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 42vw;
  height: 42vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255, 62, 62);
  background-color: rgb(253, 133, 133);
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="optionToChooseBackground">
  <div id="optionToChoose">
    <h3>Choose a style want to change :</h3>
    <h4>Border</h4>
    <p>borderColor</p>
    <p>backgroundColor</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="clockOuterCircle" class="restyleBackground"></div>
```

Comment: But how is the picker removed

Comment: You were trying to create picker in everyclick, I change this behavior to, only create when first click. 
If you find this helpful please upvode and accept answer :)

Comment: No that is not what I want as creating event for each click will be cumbersome as there will be more properties not only 2 that why I wanted to remove the picker when clicked outside

Comment: If you know the way : How to know there is element is present with certain class inside a tag . Like here appended a certain element with class , is there a method to know that if till now element is appended or not

Comment: @Rana Ok, check this again. Also notice that, your code is already hard coded, when you check  "border" or "background" in the end. But desired part modified as you wanted :)

Comment: what do you mean by hard coded

Comment: You said my previous answer to cumbersome as other elements will add. Eventually, you have to code for each one a new if statement end of the code. Hovever, this is the smplier.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort @Muhammedogz brother , very very thank you . Upvoted your answer

Comment: No problem :) Please do not to forget accept answer.

Answer (score -2):

When you open the datepicker You must create a transparent div that fill the screen but below the selector and add the closing event to it.

Comment: Please read [answer]. Your answer is way to broad und unspecific.